# How to sync data between two independent backends?

Tags: javascript, java

I want to sync data between two different backends, one written in Javascript and the other in Java.
The JS backend has its data stored in a MongoDB but the Java backend contains some hardcoded data that I need to fetch in order to store it the DB of the JS backend.

Now my question is what are the possible solutions to do that from an architecture perspective?

Comment: If the Java data is hardcoded, why is a "sync" required?

Comment: Cause now I'm writing a service just to avoid hardcoding some configs but instead use a UI and store them in the DB, the whole point is to eliminate hardcoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a "Split-Brain". You can only use one Data Store. You have to migrate the Hardcoded Date to MangoDB an to read the data from there.

Comment: Yes MongoDB but MangoDB is much sweeter